# What makes procesess internally reversible?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, reversibility

So I read that processes where there is no thermal gradients in the system are internally reversible, but for other cases, do we have to consider the temperature of boundary to calculate entropy change? What does this model of using boundary temperature do? Does it account for heat generation inside the system or does it consider it thrown outside?

So how does temp gradient in the system relate to irreversibility quantitatively? And to calculate entropy generation as a whole, do we need to consider whole universe or only system  and surrounding separately, I mean for heat transfer between 2 thermal reservoirs with large heat capacities ( infinite) at finite temp difference, the system heat gen is zero but in universe, entropy is generated. So how do we spatially account for entropy generation in any general case, or can we only find entropy generation in universe as a whole?
I am quite confused about this.

So basically two questions:
How to map entropy generation in a general case?
Why does considering boundary temperature help in determining overall entropy generation inside the system(in case of non uniform temperature inside the system)?

Comment: This question includes multiple questions in one, it needs more focus and should be re-written or closed. Spell checking would also not hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways by which the entropy of a closed system (no mass flow in or out) can change:

1. Entropy transfer across the boundary interface between the system and its surroundings.  This is equal to the integral of $dQ/T_B$, where dQ is the amount of heat flowing across the system boundary from the surroundings and $T_B$ is the temperature of the portion of the boundary through which dQ flows.  For a reversible process, this is the only mechanism for entropy change and, in this case, $T_B$ is equal to the system temperature (which is uniform throughout the system, including at the boundary).
2. Entropy generation within the system as a result of process irreversibility.  This entropy generation is caused by (a) finite heat conduction within the system as a consequence of finite temperature gradients, (b) viscous dissipation of mechanical energy to internal energy within the system as a consequence of finite velocity gradients, (c) molecular diffusion within the system as a consequence of finite concentration gradients, and (d) changes is chemical composition within the system as a consequence of finite chemical reaction rates.

Comment: Many thanks, but I have a problem in attributing the entropy generation to space, is all entropy generation attributable spatially, i.e, can we map all entropy generation to a particular region in space , If not in what cases?

Comment: As in cases where there is heat transfer with finite temperature difference but negligible thermal gradients as in case of phase transformation or case of infinite heat capacity or thermal conductivity, where do we account for entropy generation spatially?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are asking where the entropy generation is occurring when we have transfer of heat between two ideal constant temperature reservoirs at different temperatures.  Is that it?

Comment: If you want to have a better understanding of entropy generation and how it is distributed spatially within a fluid system undergoing an irreversible change, see Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, Chapter 11, Problem 11.D.1, Equation of change for entropy.  This was a real awakening for me.

Comment: Yes, in all such cases where the entropy generation is not apparent where to ascribe those to? And how is taking the value of $$\delta s =\delta q/T_{b}+ s_{gen}$$  is a definition of entropy transfer accounting for all the entropy change occuring inside the system including entropy generation.

Comment: Thanks Sir for the wonderful references

Comment: I don't quite understand your question.  The equation you wrote is not a definition of entropy transfer.  The entropy transfer is $\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}$.  The total entropy change of the system for an irreversible process is $$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}+S_{gen}=\int{\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}}$$where $Q_{rev}$ is the heat transferred over a reversible path between the same initial and final states of the system (as for the irreversible path), and T is the system temperature variation over the reversible path.

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant the transfer term there, why does it have $\delta q/ T_{b}$ to account for the whole entropy transfer? Is it because , the boundary itself is interacting and hthe bulk has nothing to do with the interaction.

Comment: I am sorry I got a bit confused with whole wntropy change and entropy transfer due to heat.

Comment: It has more to do with the empirical development of the 2nd law and of our understanding.  Later, with analyses like that in the reference I gave you, it became obvious from a more fundamental point of view.